# How do I make ghost home page on a subdir?

Tags: ghost-blog

I am attempting to run ghost with the Ghost home page, normally displayed at `/`, instead displayed on the `/blog` subdir of my site.

I have followed the [Ghost routing docs](https://ghost.org/docs/themes/routing/) and the [Ghost forum post](https://forum.ghost.org/t/clarifying-custom-home-page-routing/2613/2) come up with the following `routes.yaml`:

```
routes:

collections:
  /blog/:
    permalink: /{slug}/
    template: index

taxonomies:
  tag: /tag/{slug}/
  author: /author/{slug}/
```

After starting ghost and visiting http://localhost:2368/blog (or http://localhost:2368/blog/), the page shows:

> 404
>
> Page not found
>
> Go to the front page →

The 'Go to the front page →' is a link to the same page - `/blog`.

And in my logs:

```
[2021-01-26 17:54:58] INFO "GET /blog/" 404 88ms
```

**How do I make ghost home page on a subdir?**

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this by:

- Making `config.development.json` and `config.production.json` include `/blog` in the `url` setting. Eg: `"url": "http://localhost:2368/blog",`
- Using the default `routes.yaml` file is as below - since `url` is `/blog`, everything in `routes.yaml` will be relative to that:

```
# EVERYTHING HERE IS RELATIVE TO '/blog' - see `url` in config.(environment).json

routes:

collections:
  /:
    permalink: /{slug}/
    template: index

taxonomies:
  tag: /tag/{slug}/
  author: /author/{slug}/
```